# Where do I obtain x86 wlanapi.dll for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, wlanapi

Running Dependency Walker for my 32-bit dll shows that I require wlanapi.dll (x86) which was missing from my Microsoft Server 2008 R2 machine. The following post mentions that Wireless LAN service needs to be installed http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2008/06/02/122558.aspx

I did so, but it installed only the x64 version. Any idea how I can get the x86 version ?

Comment: It seems to be a redistribution issue of a 3rd party dll. I was trying to avoid installing the 3rd party software and tried copying dlls (yes,bad ,I know, but I wanted to fix the problem temporarily). Installing the software resolved the above situation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a redistribution issue of a 3rd party dll. I was trying to avoid installing the 3rd party software and tried copying dlls (yes,bad ,I know, but I wanted to fix the problem temporarily). Installing the software resolved the above situation.

P.S.: A web search did not provide any details of a 32 bit wlanapi.dll.